# Access a TextField from another ViewController

Tags: viewcontroller

i have a problem with my code, i think.
Im trying to read out data from a textfield, which is on another view controller, but every time i try to access the text of the textfield its give me NULL.
I declared a instance of the SecondViewController and a property like this:

```
FirstViewController:

SecondViewController* controller;
@property (nonatomic, assign) SecondViewController* controller;
```

And with this Method i will access the text:

```
FirstViewController:

controller = [[[SecondViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
test = controller.textField.text;
NSLog(@"%@", test);
```

I also maked a forward Class declaration and imported the Header. The textField is also declared as property. And the "test" is a NSString in my FirstViewController with a property.

Why the NSLog() gives me (NULL)? I don't understand it...

P.S. Sorry for my bad English

Greetings